# React JS get data from database using axios.get(url) with param

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get data from a database using axios in React.  Unfortunately for some reason the url I use doesn't return data although in the browser it does. The url contains a parameter, which is most likely a problem because when I use an url without a parameter, the data is returned.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId : this.props.match.params.userId,
            users:[]
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/getUser?userId=1";

        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/getUser", {params: {
            userId: this.state.userId
            }})
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({users: data})
            });

        console.log(this.state.users);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to get database data correctly using REST API and axios?

Comment: You should probably look at the console and network log in your browser to diagnose the issue, as well as logging on the server. You can see if any errors are being shown, and you can see the exact request and response.

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/getUser", {
 params: {
        userId: this.state.userId
        }
 })
 .then(response => response.json()) // You need to parse JSON
 .then((data) => {
    this.setState({users: data})
 });
```

Only difference is in first .then, you need to parse data to JSON.